# echo variable in window location not working

Tags: php, variables, echo

im trying to redirect a user to a url with a php variable $userdata
However the script seems not to work, it does put it in the html (confirmed with inspect element) but it does not redirect.
the url needs to bee

```
$first = $user['first'];;
$second= $user['second'];;
$userdata  = "'.$first.'&hello='.$second.'";
echo "<script> window.location = 'example/login?userid='.$userdata.'' </script>";
```

Comment: Why are you putting `.` around the variables? You're substituting the variables inside the string, not concatenating, so you don't need `.`.

Comment: what needs the url to be and what is the url? `$first` and `$second` look as if they require [`urlencode()`](https://php.net/urlencode) and as both are from $user, check [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query) function, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to convert the PHP string to a properly formatted JavaScript string. Than use JavaScript concatenation to combine it with the string in the `<script>`.

```
$first = $user['first'];;
$second= $user['second'];;
$userdata  = "$first&hello=$second";
echo "<script> window.location = 'example/login?userid=' + " . json_encode($userdata) . ";</script>";
```